# Create a 2mA charger for ML2032

Tags: battery-charging, lm317

I'm trying to create a simple LM317-based ML2023 charger. Unfortunately, I have very limited electronic skills.
According to the [ML2032 datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/310103.pdf), the charging voltage of the ML2032 must not exceed 3.3V, and the charging current must not exceed 2mA.

According to the [LM317 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf), when used as a constant current source, the charging current will be 1.25V/620Ω = 2.016mA.

[image: Circuit]

Will the above circuit work? If not, what would be the easiest, beginner-friendly circuit that'll meet the charging requirements?

Comment: The battery data sheet recommends a charging circuit so why not use that.

Comment: R1 is supposed to be **in series** with the load (your battery) when the LM317 is used as a constant current regulator. See Figure 9 of https://docs.rs-online.com/0054/0900766b813862fa.pdf.

Comment: The friendly datasheet of LM317 states that recommended operating conditions is a minimum output current of 10mA. Therefore it is a bad regulator for your purposes - it risks becoming unstable. You need a better regulator. Or otherwise maybe just load it with a dummy load like a fixed resistor to ground.

Answer (score 2):

> Will the above circuit work?

As mentioned in comments, no it won't.

> *If not, what would be the easiest, beginner-friendly circuit that'll
> meet the charging requirements?*

If you read the [data sheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/310103.pdf) thoroughly you'll see this (in the red box I added): -

[image]

So, if you have a stable voltage supply (say 5 volts) then you can make a resistive potential divider that produces (say) 3.2 volts at the battery connection terminals. You ensure that the net Thevenin resistance of the potential divider cannot produce more than 2 mA when a discharged battery is applied. The data sheet suggests that a discharged battery might be as low as 2 volts hence, you have the numbers to calculate the Thevenin resistance when using a stable 5 volt supply.

Two resistors has got to be the easiest beginner-friendly circuit.

Or, if you want something a tad more sophisticated pick a 3.2 volt regulator of the type mentioned (S-812C series) available from [Mouser](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/ABLIC/S-812C32AY-Z2-U?qs=sE1HjTVAc2i%252B%2F6HI5FZz%252BQ%3D%3D) in a non-surface-mount package.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! `Or, if you want something a tad more sophisticated pick a 3.2 volt regulator of the type mentioned (S-812C series) available from Mouser in a non-surface-mount package.` I saw that circuit, but I couldn't figure out what the voltage the regulator needs to provide before the diode. Since the LM317 can also be used as an adjustable voltage regulator, what voltage does it need to be set to to work in that circuit?
I know that the diode will cause a voltage drop of about .5V. If I use a 3.3 regulator won't the actual voltage be 2.8V. I.e. =.2V below full charge?

Comment: Yes, the diode will drop a voltage but it will be probably in the region of 100 mV when the battery is nearing full charge i.e. very close to 3.2 volts because the charging current at that point will be in the microamps region. You don't need a diode of course if all you are doing is connecting the battery to the charger (already powered) and t you disconnect the charger from the battery whilst it is still powered @NemoXXX

Answer (score 2):

The LM317 needs something like 3.5mA typically to operate (depending on voltage differential, temperature, etc. it can be as high as 10mA) so it would supply a *higher* current than 2mA if it could.

However it also needs at least the battery voltage plus 4.25V to regulate reliably (1.25V plus 3V of headroom) as explained in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) and you are only giving it 2V to work with, so there’s a second reason it won’t work.